# Is there a way to bulk add data to salesforce

Tags: custom-field, data

I am trying to fill a bunch of fields with different text data but wanted to know if there is an easier way instead of going from one object to the other.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are trying to modify data, in which case you should look into [Data Loader](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Data_Loader). There are versions for Windows and Mac. You can also use [dataloader.io](https://dataloader.io/) if you are so inclined. Either way, create a CSV with your data and upload it.

If you want to mass create new fields (modifying metadata), that is a different tool set, but it does not sound like what you are looking for.